# How can i break my continuous loop, if a input is received from user side and continue with the loop

Tags: php

How can i break my continuous loop, if a input is received from user side and continue with the loop

```
<?php
{
   //first part of code
}

//endless loop, based on the first part, until an onclick method sends an ajax request?
while (1)
{
   ...
   if ($variable_is_set_by_button_press) break;
}

{
   //last part of code giving me some feedback about execution time and such
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want this? Typically, I would suggest processing `ajax` as a different request.

Comment: Are you sure this is PHP and not JavaScript? If so, please explain better, because PHP produces a page on the server and has nothing to do with onclicks on that page at the client side.

Comment: As Vedran has said, PHP isn't usable at the client level. And its generally a 'locking' language and can't be interrupted by anything but PHP. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You probably want to use AJAX, the thing is, that php is server side, so every `$variable_is_set_by_button_press` is probably generated by either GET/POST request. What you are looking for is asynchronously change the request. Kinda.

Comment: Why is everyone assuming the OP wants client side PHP? :) Read the Q: *...until an onclick method sends an **ajax request**?*

Comment: @OneTrickPony Probably because people are assuming that this script will take up unnecessary resources while executing.  The number of clients is unknown.  The timeout in the php.ini file is unknown.  The purpose behind this piece of code is unknown.  The question is clear, but its efficiency and effectiveness is not.  You would usually call a separate script if you want a new action, not loop through a script and rely upon a client (or timeout) to request (or submit) a new action.

Answer (score 0):

These language constructs are made especially for loops, maybe it will help:

`break` - breaks out of the loop,

`continue` - goes to the next looping procedure.

Comment: OP has no problem with `break` or `continue` !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but you could achieve it by controlling the loop with a database variable:

```
while (checkDatabaseVariable() == true) {
// DO STUFF
}
```

You could then set this variable to false with a different script and your PHP loop should detect the change and break out of the loop.

Comment: Most servers will kill the script after a short time, won't they?

Comment: Well yes, but this can be adjusted with `set_time_limit()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: I know, but you'd need to be server admin for that, avoid safe mode,... it's a terrible thing to do. Your answer is ok (although, I'd use sessions), but the OP's concept is flawed and should be changed (when he explains better what he wants).

Comment: `set_time_limit()` **only** works when safe mode is disabled. I have changed this successfully with a number of shared hosting accounts. But I agree, the original idea is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use APC. Assuming your loop runs in `script1.php`, with ajax:

```
while(1){
  if(apc_fetch($user . '_stop'))
    break;
}
```

When the button is pressed, you trigger another ajax request to `script2.php`:

```
apc_store($user . '_stop', 1);
```

`$user` can be a session ID or a hash of the current user IP, User-agent etc.

Answer (score 0):

@tyrhus is 100% right.
PHP is executed on the server side, not at the client (browser).

So, if you want to react upon user's input, you should use AJAX and to do async request to the server when that happens.